# SASS won't build if brackets in path of project folder in Sublime Text

Tags: ruby, sass, sublimetext3, sublimetext, compass

I am getting a problem where Sublime Text will not compile SASS if the project directory has any brackets/parentheses `()` in its path.

In my case having brackets in the path is unavoidable as we use Dropbox for business, which insists on naming it's root folder `Dropbox (Company Name)`.

Is there either:

a) A workaround such as a virtual folder that can be set up

I've already considered `mklink \D "C:\Dropbox" "C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox (My Company Name)"` to try making a virtual directory "C:\Dropbox" which points to my actual Dropbox folder, but it ended up working more like a shortcut. So when I clicked the virtual folder, I was then back in the original folder with the brackets etc.

b) A way to alter a setting or config for sass/sublime/ruby so that it works with brackets in the path

Or any other workaround or idea to mitigate the problem?

Comment: Which SASS plugin for Sublime are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a [directory junction](https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link) instead of a symbolic link:

```
mklink /J "C:\Dropbox" "C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox (My Company Name)"
```

This makes Windows (and more importantly, Sublime) think that `C:\Dropbox` is an actual folder, and will build the path based on it instead of the target of the symlink you created earlier.